# Ошибка в коде бот телеграмм отправка видео

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

помогите пожалуйста я пишу анонимный чат бот в телеграмме уже всё сделал кроме отправки видео выдаёт ошибку `bot.send_video(chat_info[1], message.video[-1].file_id) TypeError: 'Video' object is not subscriptable`

вот сам код:

````
def bot_video(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        chat_info = db.get_active_chat(message.chat.id)
        if chat_info != False:
            bot.send_video(chat_info[1], message.video[-1].file_id)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '❌Вы не начали диалог!')```
````

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `message.video[-1].file_id` это `message.video.file_id`

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.send_video(chat_info[1], message.video.file_id)
```

Для отправки видео не требуется индексация, насколько могу помнить